# Displaying filename in GridView asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am getting this ~/Data/TestCopy.pdf for my Documents in the GridView but I am trying to get only the filename without the directory from SQL database. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

```
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Documents " SortExpression="filePath">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("filePath") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>                                
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("filePath") %>'
                        NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("filePath") %>'>
                    </asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is, just add the Reference to System.IO and use Path class to get only the file name, little change in your code,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Documents " SortExpression="filePath">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Path.GetFileName(Bind("filePath")) %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>                                
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" runat="server" Text='<%# Path.GetFileName(Bind("filePath")) %>'
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("filePath") %>'>
                </asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I have added the reference to system.IO in my .cs but it said that the path is not in the current context.

Comment: please try to use complete namespace of path like,Text='<%# System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Bind("filePath")) %>'

Comment: i have done that but now i have thi instead: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context

Comment: plz try to replace bind with Eval, like ,Text='<%# System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Eval("filePath")) %>' Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In Gridview RowDataBound , evaluate filename from filepath.

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath).
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try something like this:-

```
Text='<%# Eval("filePath").ToString().Split(Eval("filePath").ToString().LastIndexOf("/"))[1] %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have stored it this way ~/Data/TestCopy.pdf in the database. You can use split function to split the last '/'